# List is unsorted after sorting an array from Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase

I want to create a sorted list by date from an array of documents from firebase. The usage is an inbox for a ChatView.
When i load the InboxView, I group all messages between two users into a ConversationContainer`.

These ConversationContainers are then displayed in a list in the InboxView.
Also, the field `lastMessage` is updated every time a new message is sent in the conversation. When the `Conversation` object is created, it takes the `lastMessage` timestamp from the container.

The idea is, that the `ConversationContainer` with the lastest message is always on top of the list. But my list is kind of random.
Not randomised every time, but I keep getting this order of the "sorted" timestamps:

```
10-08-2023
03-08-2023
09-08-2023 
03-08-2023 
08-08-2023
```

My current approach looks like this:

Data-structure:

```
struct ConversationContainer: Identifiable, Codable, Hashable {
 var id = "\(UUID())" 
var user1: String = "" 
var user2: String = "" 
var lastMessage:Double = Date().timeIntervalSince1970
 }
```

ListView:

```
@State private var conversations = [Conversation]()

List(sortConversations()) { convo in
 convo
 }
```

sortConversations():

```
func sortConversations() -> [Conversation] {
 return conversations.sorted(by: { $0.lastMessage > $1.lastMessage })
 }
```

The ongoing conversations are fetched onAppear:

```
let convos = await net.getConversationIDs(userID: net.myUser.id) for id in convos { conversations.append(Conversation(id: id)) }
```

Comment: Can you please show us the array that holds those dates?